# PyQt5: phantom columns when using QTableView.setSortingEnabled and QSortFilterProxyModel

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qtableview

I have a custom Qt table model that allows a user to add both columns and rows after it's been created. I'm trying to display this table using a QSortFilterProxyModel / QTableView setup, but I'm getting strange behavior when I try and enable sorting on the table view. My view launches and displays the added data correctly:

[image: View at launch]

However, when I click on one of the column headers (to sort), phantom columns are added to the view.

[image: View after header click]

Has anyone seen this before or know whats going on? I'm admittedly a novice still with Qt, so maybe I'm just approaching this the wrong way. Thanks.

```
# -*- mode:python; mode:auto-fill; fill-column:79; coding:utf-8 -*-

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

# =====================================================================
# =====================================================================
class SimpleProxyModel(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def filterAcceptsColumn(self, col, index):
        return True

# =====================================================================
# =====================================================================
class SimpleModel(QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self):
        super(SimpleModel, self).__init__()
        self._data = {}

    def rowCount(self, index=QModelIndex()):
        if len(self._data.values()) > 0:
            return len(self._data.values()[0])
        else:
            return 0

    def columnCount(self, index=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self._data.keys())

    def data( self, index, role = Qt.DisplayRole ):
        row, col = index.row(), index.column()

        if ( not index.isValid() or
             not ( 0 <= row < self.rowCount() ) or
             not ( 0 <= col < self.columnCount() ) ):
            return QVariant()

        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QVariant( self._data[col][row] )

        return QVariant()

    def addData( self, col, val):

        new_col = False
        # Turn on flag for new column
        if col not in self._data.keys():
            new_col = True

        if new_col:
            self.beginInsertColumns(QModelIndex(), self.columnCount(),self.columnCount())
            # Catch this column up with the others by adding blank rows
            self._data[col] = [""] * self.rowCount()

        self.beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), self.rowCount(), self.rowCount())
        # Add data to each column, either the value specified or a blank
        for i in range(self.columnCount()):
            if i == col:
                self._data[i].append(val)
            else:
                self._data[i].append( "" )
        self.endInsertRows()

        if new_col:
            self.endInsertColumns()


# =====================================================================
# =====================================================================
class SimpleView(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        super(SimpleView, self).__init__(parent)

        self._mainmodel = None
        self._proxymodel = None
        self._tableview = QTableView()
        self._tableview.setSortingEnabled(True)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget( self._tableview )

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def setModel(self, model):

        self._mainmodel = model
        proxy = SimpleProxyModel()
        proxy.setSourceModel(model)
        self._tableview.setModel(proxy)

# =====================================================================
# =====================================================================
app = QApplication([])

v = SimpleView()
m = SimpleModel()
v.setModel( m )

m.addData(0,1)
m.addData(0,2)
m.addData(1,3)

v.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Thanks @tmoreau, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem was in my `SimpleModel.addData` method, and is related to how I nested the column and row inserts. If you change this method to first insert new columns, and then insert new rows, the phantom columns don't show up.

```
def addData( self, col, val):                                               

    if col not in self._data.keys():                                        
        self.beginInsertColumns(QModelIndex(), self.columnCount(),self.columnCount())
        # Catch this column up with the others by adding blank rows         
        self._data[col] = [""] * self.rowCount()                            
        self.endInsertColumns()                                             

    self.beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), self.rowCount(), self.rowCount())   
    # Add data to each column, either the value specified or a blank        
    for i in range(self.columnCount()):                                     
        if i == col:                                                        
            self._data[i].append(val)                                       
        else:                                                               
            self._data[i].append( "" )                                      
    self.endInsertRows()
```

Answer (score 2):

The Qt documentation is fairly clear on this. You must call [endInsertRows](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#endInsertRows) after [beginInsertRows](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginInsertRows), and [endInsertColumns](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#endInsertColumns) after [beginInsertColumns](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginInsertColumns).

The most pertinent point from the last link above is this:

> Note: This function emits the columnsAboutToBeInserted() signal which
>   connected views (or proxies) must handle before the data is inserted.
>   Otherwise, the views may end up in an invalid state.

So you must call `endInsertColum()` **before** beginning any other insertions/deletions.

Comment: you seem to be a wizard when it comes to python stuff. Do you do freelance work at all?

Comment: @JokerMartini. Thanks for asking, but due to other commitments, I'm unable to take on freelance work at the moment.

Comment: that's a bummer. I have a feq python things I need help with and would live to have you help out. One I posted as a question on here SO.